# Twilio alphanumeric sender id: reason for id mismatch

Tags: twilio

There is a customer with a phone number from the UAE. And there is registered alphanumeric sender id - **Name1**.
When I try to send an SMS with 'From' - **Name1**, a completely different id (let's call it **Name2**) comes to the customer.
Getting sent SMS message using Twilio api, I see that:

```
{
  ...
  "from": "Name1"
  ...
}
```

How does this happen?
How is **Name1** to **Name2** mapping done?
What exactly does the twilio send to the carrier? Is the sender's phone number transmitted in addition to the alphanumeric ID?
Сan **Name2** be the default value for sender phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The mapping from one sender ID to another isn't done by Twilio. It is normally done by carriers, so there is no control over it. The [guidelines for sending SMS to UAE](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/ae/sms) do say that carriers in the UAE heavily filter SMS traffic and that unregistered sender IDs will be replaced with generic alphanumeric sender IDs.

I am surprised that your registered alphanumeric sender ID is being over-ridden though.

I would get in contact with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide the message SIDs of some messages where this happened and they will be able to investigate or guide you further.